# How to filter multiple conditions in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to filter my table with 2 conditions:

1. ride_length must be greater than 31
2. For the trips that have both same start_station_name and end_station_name, the ride_length must be greater than 60

I try the query code with a subquery as below:

```
SELECT 
TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ended_at,started_at,SECOND) AS ride_length,
start_station_name,
end_station_name
FROM
divvy_stations_trips.all_trips 
WHERE 
TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ended_at,started_at,SECOND) > 31 AND
(SELLECT
 TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ended_at,started_at,SECOND)
 FROM 
 divvy_stations_trips.all_trips
 WHERE 
 TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ended_at,started_at,SECOND)>60 AND
 start_station_name = end_station_name 
 )
```

I get this error: *Syntax error: Parenthesized expression cannot be parsed as an expression, struct constructor, or subquery at [10:9]*

It seems my subquery has issue? Anyone of you can help will be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subquery you have created cannot be used in the WHERE clause.

One approach would be to use a `UNION` to combine two sets of results.

This should work:

```
(SELECT 
TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ended_at,started_at,SECOND) AS ride_length,
start_station_name,
end_station_name
FROM
divvy_stations_trips.all_trips 
WHERE 
TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ended_at,started_at,SECOND) > 31 AND 
start_station_name != end_station_name)

UNION ALL

(SELECT 
TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ended_at,started_at,SECOND) AS ride_length,
start_station_name,
end_station_name
FROM
divvy_stations_trips.all_trips 
WHERE 
TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ended_at,started_at,SECOND) > 60 AND 
start_station_name = end_station_name)
```

Comment: This really works! Thanks for showing me a new way to query results, learn a lot from you @dnnshssm ! :)